# How do I properly secure zipline anchor to brick?

Tags: brick

I would like to learn how to properly secure an anchor for a zipline to the side of my house and confirm the type of anchor to use. I've read this [previous thread](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/68357/9072) but have different requirements.

I am planning to attach it just above the garage door where there are 3 LVL's behind the brick.

[image]
[image]

For the anchor, I've found a few options; which one is best and how would I go about ensuring it's secured to the LVL's behind the brick?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The requirements are still the same from the other thread.  Probably more so because of the LVLs.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate  The OP has a link to another similar question asked by another user.  My wording is the problem.

Comment: Attaching soundly to lvls is just a matter of through bolts that are big enough combined with big washers. That said, did you not get the takeaway from the referenced question that this is a really bad idea? Walls hold stuff up; they aren’t designed to resist pull from the side.

Comment: I am not concerned with the wall resisting pull from the side

Comment: I’m concerned that the OP isn’t concerned. But hey, it’s your house, right?

Comment: Something-something freedom 'murica. You should not be concerned.

Comment: I too want to repeat that this is a bad idea.  Bricks are not that strong.  And a brick wall is not designed for sideways force.  In fact, it is normally tied to a structure behind it so that it doesn't fall down.  I am assuming that in your country bricks refer to clay bricks, not concrete.

Comment: You should endeavor to fasten your zip line anchor *through* the garage door header, i.e. you need a big washer on the *inside* face of the header.  Not fastened to the brick.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear -- I plan to fasten *through* the 3 LVL's